# Php preg_match with wild card characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have some zip code in an array which includes some wild card characters  like this

```
$zip_codes = array( '12556', '765547', '234*', '987*' );
$target_zip = '2347890';
```

So to check whether the target zip is already present in the array. I am doing like this

```
foreach( $zip_codes as $zip ) {
  if ( preg_match( "/{$target_zip}.*$/i", $zip ) ) {
    echo 'matched';
    break;
  }
  else {
    echo 'not matched';
  }
}
```

But its not matching the zip at all. Can someone tell me whats the issue here?

Comment: 2347890 is not in the array right?

Comment: Yes its not in array. But it should match as 234* has wild card character.

Comment: I think so too, it should be the other way around. But note that `234*` matches `23` or `234` or `2344444`

Comment: You probably want `preg_match('/' . str_replace('*', '.*', $zip) . '/', $target_zip)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird 234* should match 234 with all the characters after that.

Comment: @Thefourthbird `234*` would match `237`

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn your `$zip` values into valid regular expressions by converting `*` into `.*` (or perhaps `\d*`); then you can test them against `$target_zip`:

```
$zip_codes = array( '12556', '765547', '234*', '987*' );
$target_zip = '2347890';

foreach( $zip_codes as $zip ) {
    echo $zip;
    if (preg_match('/' . str_replace('*', '.*', $zip) . '/', $target_zip)) {
        echo ' matched'. PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo ' not matched' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12556 not matched
765547 not matched
234* matched
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fnpJs)

You haven't indicated whether you want the value in `$zip_codes` to match the entire `$target_zip` value or just part of it. The code above will work for just part (i.e. `234` will match `12345`); if you don't want that, change the regex construction to:

```
if (preg_match('/^' . str_replace('*', '.*', $zip) . '$/', $target_zip)) {
```

The anchors will ensure that `$zip` matches the entirety of `$target_zip`.

Comment: Preg_quote the input?

Comment: @Andreas if you `preg_quote` the input the `*` will be replaced with `\*` and then you'd have to undo that. Given that it's only digits and `*` it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I meant after the str_replace, but sure.. I usually are careful with inputs and regex. You never know....

Comment: @Andreas If you do it after the `str_replace` the `*` won't act as a 0 or more quantifier

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that using `234*` in a regex will match any number of `4`'s.

The other problem is that you match to the end (using `$`) but not the start, so `789` (with the `.*` appended) will also match (as it's in the middle).  In this code, I use `^{$zip}$`, with `*` replaced with `.*` to match any trailing characters...

```
$zip_codes = array( '12556', '765547', '789', '234', '234*', '987*' );
$target_zip = '2347890';

foreach( $zip_codes as $zip ) {
    $zip = str_replace("*", ".*", $zip);
    if ( preg_match( "/^{$zip}$/i", $target_zip ) ) {
        echo $zip.' matched'.PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo $zip.' not matched'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here.

You can look for `*` and based on that look for an exact on the number of characters -1.

```
$zip_codes = array( '12556', '765547', '234*', '987*' );
$target_zip = '2347890';


foreach($zip_codes as $zip){
    if(strpos($zip, "*") !== false){
      //if "234* -1 = "234"    == substr("2347890",0,3)
        if(substr($zip, 0, -1) == substr($target_zip, 0, strlen($zip)-1)){
            echo "wildcard match";
        }
    }else{
        if($zip == $target_zip){
            echo "excat match";
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/hIGER

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the loop, the pattern is always the same:

`if ( preg_match( "/2347890.*$/i", $zip ) ) {`

I think you meant to use the value of `$zip` as part of the pattern, which causes the issue repeating the last digit 0+ times in:

```
if ( preg_match( "/234*.*$/i", $zip ) ) {
                     ^^
```

---

As an alternative, you could also extract the digits from `$zip_codes` using a capturing group and match optional following `*`

```
^(\d+)\**$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgbYPo/1)

Then use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the `target_zip` start with the extracted digits.

```
$zip_codes = array( '12556', '765547', '234*', '987*', '237' );
$target_zip = '2347890';

foreach($zip_codes as $zip ) {
    $digitsOnly = preg_replace("~^(\d+)\**$~", "$1", $zip);
    if (strpos($target_zip, $digitsOnly) === 0) {
        echo "$zip matched $target_zip" . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo "$zip not matched $target_zip" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
12556 not matched 2347890
765547 not matched 2347890
234* matched 2347890
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Thrq5)